# Ошибка при написании телеграмм бота на python в Dispatcher'е с библиотеки aiogramm

Tags: python-3.x

У меня проблема при написании телеграмм бота с помощью библиотеки aiogramm. Ошибка invalid syntax происходит в Dispatcher'е при вызове функции. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо :)[image: Вот такая.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не закрыты круглые скобки в строках с декораторами `@dp.message_handler`